# Как заставить тег video воспроизводить mkv в браузере Mozilla?

Tags: html5, firefox, видео

Браузер Mozilla не воспроизводит mkv файлы в теге `<video>`.
Можно ли как-нибудь его заставить воспроизводить?
Собственно, вот код, в Chrome воспроизводится, но без звука. В Mozilla вообще не воспроизводится:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <title>Заголовок страницы</title> 
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Описание страницы">
    </head>
 <body>
    </video controls width="300" height="200">
        <source src="movie3.mkv">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Можно, конечно, переконвертировать самому, но не вариант. Ведь как-то же работают всякие youtube, и куча других видеосервисов, которые поддерживают огромное количество форматов.

Comment: Покажите используемую разметку и уточните, пожалуйста, допустима ли установка сторонних кодеков перед воспроизведением видео в систему или воспроизведение должно работать сразу из коробки? Уточните, можете ли вы сами сконвертировать файл из `.mkv` в `.mp4` или допустим только формат `.mkv`? Все уточнения внесите в сам вопрос.

Comment: Не изобретайте велосипед! Используйте youtube, заливайте туда видео через API. Это Вам даст гарантии доступности видео в популярных браузерах и платформах. Подробнее читайте https://webref.ru/html/video. HTML5 еще не готов для такого использования.

Comment: youtube как раз и преобразовывает загружаемые файлы в нужные, что бы потом все воспроизводилось.

Comment: А это точная информация, что youtube преобразовывает?

Comment: Нет, ютьюб поддерживает далеко не все форматы: https://support.google.com/youtube/troubleshooter/2888402?hl=ru Так что конвертированием придётся заняться, ибо HTML не сможет понять матрёшку (точнее в браузерах с кодеками проблемы, но не суть). Да и зачем такие увесистые файлы в вебе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно документации Mozilla

> Открытые медиа Firefox может воспроизводить формат контейнера WAV (типы файлов .wav, .wave), содержащий несжатое аудио в виде PCM с 8
>   или 16 бит на канал.
>
> Vorbis аудио, Opus аудио, Theora видео и VP8 видео являются открытыми
>   форматами сжатия аудио/видео для использования без патентных
>   ограничений. Они могут быть просмотрены в Firefox, если они встроены в
>   следующие форматы контейнеров: Ogg (типы файлов .ogg, .oga, .ogv,
>   .ogx, .spx, .opus) или WebM (типы файлов .webm).
>
> Патентованные медиа MP3, AAC и H.264/MPEG-4 AVC являются
>   патентованными форматами сжатия аудио/видео. Они могут быть
>   просмотрены в Firefox с помощью встроенных библиотек ОС (поэтому ни
>   Mozilla, ни вы не должны платить сбор), если они встроены в контейнер
>   формата MP4 (типы файлов .mp4, .m4a, .m4p, .m4b, .m4r, .m4v).

Для воспроизведения иных форматов видео нужно использовать в браузере сторонние приложения или плагины. То есть для решения Вашей проблемы либо установить на сайте информацию о том, что для просмотра необходим какой-либо плагин для браузера, либо перегружать видео в другом формате.

Comment: А можно ли добавить на сайт (загрузить на сервер) плагин и сделать так, чтобы этот плагин открывался у пользователя при воспроизведении видео (ну типа написать программу)? Тогда-то по-любому же должно воспроизводиться. А теги <embed> или <object> - с их помощью тоже не получится воспроизводить сторонние плагины, они же вроде для этого и предназначены?

Comment: @ПавелИгорев нет, нельзя, т. к. необходимость в плагинах обусловлена отсутствием нужных прав доступа. Явные действия по установке со стороны пользователя всё равно потребуются.